# How Parse JSON in Java

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

This is my Java code:

```
...
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
JSONObject serverResponse = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));
String error = serverResponse.getString("error");
text1.setText(error);
...
```

I can not parse JSON.

JSON:

```
[{"error":"1"}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis, Instead 1 indicates nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `jsonObject` is within the `jsonArray`

Do like this

```
JSONArray jarray= new JSONArray(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));
String error=jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("error");
```

Comment: Nambi Narayanan, Thank you!

Comment: @Aydomir It's Ok Glad i would help :)